# why the webmaster does not read our sitemaps?

Tags: joomla, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

There is an issue in the sitemap section which is not fixed contrary to our attempt.
the webmaster does not read our sitemaps, in spite the fact that  are sitemaps are completely fine and they work properly. We tested our sitemaps in the other websites and they worked without any problems.
We have been in too trouble according to this issue and we have faced so many damages, we would be pleased if anyone can help us as soon as possible. what can we do in order to solve this problem?
With so many thanks in advance.

website: almasp.com

Comment: siteMap: https://www.almasp.com/index.php?option=com_jmap&view=sitemap&format=xml

Comment: How do you know that Google can't read your sitemaps?  Are you getting an error from Google?   If so what is it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is unclear.  It is also not a programming question.  Questions about your website are better asked on [webmasters.se].   However, to ask there, the question needs to be clear and it needs to be applicable to other sites as well, it can't just be "tell me what is wrong with my site."

Comment: Most sites don't need XML sitemaps.  If Google isn't reading your sitemap it probably isn't even affecting your site or its SEO at all.  See my blog post: [Myth: An XML sitemap is needed for SEO; it helps rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/xml-sitemap-rankings/) and this question [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)